# Anchor links in subfolder

Tags: html, mustache

I have a strange problem. My page is in a subfolder like: **localhost:8080/folder/index.html**

Now I have an anchor link:

```
<a href="#section">Test</a>
```

When I click the link it makes a page refresh and jumps to root folder: **localhost:8080/#section**

I thought it could be some JavaScript, but when I hover the link I also see the wrong url in browser footer bar.

Shouldn't the anchor link stay on the same page? Info: The link is in a mustache template and gets dynamically inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I found the problem.

There was a base tag set.